# How do I express this in fewer lines of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'm using some JS to calculate the time since last post (ie. "Posted 2 hours ago"):

```
function ago(date) {
function render(n, unit) {
    return n + " " + unit + ((n == 1) ? "" : "s") + " ago";
}

var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 1000);

var interval = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 365));
if (Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 365)) >= 1) {
    return render(interval, "year");
}
interval = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
if (interval >= 1) {
    return render(interval, "month");
}
interval = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24));
if (interval >= 1) {
    return render(interval, "day");
}
interval = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60));
if (interval >= 1) {
    return render(interval, "hour");
}
interval = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
if (interval >= 1) {
    return render(interval, "minute");
}
interval = Math.floor(seconds);
return render(interval, "second");
}
```

And then include it on the index page, next to each post:

```
var date = 
Date.parse(document.getElementById("postedon").getAttribute("datetime"));
document.getElementById("postedago").innerHTML = ago(date);
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<time id="{{ post.postedon }}" datetime="{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}">
<span id="{{ post.postedago }}"></span>
</time>
```

Note that I'm setting the element's ID and attributes in each post's frontmatter using Liquid & YAML (with Jekyll):

```
---
date: 2018-1-4 02:00:00 +0100
postedago: postedago-post1
postedon: postedon-post2
---
```

The issue is I have to set the JS code for each post manually like this:

```
var date = 
Date.parse(document.getElementById("postedon").getAttribute("datetime"));
document.getElementById("postedago").innerHTML = ago(date);

var date = 
Date.parse(document.getElementById("postedon2").getAttribute("datetime"));
document.getElementById("postedago2").innerHTML = ago(date);

var date = 
Date.parse(document.getElementById("postedon3").getAttribute("datetime"));
document.getElementById("postedago3").innerHTML = ago(date);
```

Otherwise it won't display the time for all posts, just one.

I tried setting the element id in JS to the front matter parameter but it won't work (essentially having Jekyll replace liquid tags inside the JS file):

```
var date = 
Date.parse(document.getElementById("{{ post.postedon }}").getAttribute("datetime"));
document.getElementById("{{ post.postedago }}").innerHTML = ago(date);
```

I tried adding the front-matter dashes at the top of the js file but it still doesn't work (as referenced on SO here: [Reach Jekyll Variables With JavaScript and Pass it Throught DOM Manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853245/reach-jekyll-variables-with-javascript-and-pass-it-throught-dom-manipulation))

```
---
---
//rest of your JavaScript
```

**Maybe there's another way of doing this that I haven't thought of?**

Thanks for taking your time to read this, I really appreciate any help!

PS: Reference *timeago* script implementation on each post's page (not on the index page containing all posts): https://hejnoah.com/posts/timeago.html

Comment: Give a look at momentjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give your HTML elements a `class` attribute so that you can iterate over all of them in a loop using `getElementsByClassName()`.

HTML:

```
<time class="postedon" id="{{ post.postedon }}" datetime="{{ post.date | date_to_xmlschema }}">
    <span class="postedago" id="{{ post.postedago }}"></span>
</time>
```

JS:

```
const timeElems = document.getElementsByClassName('postedon');

for (let i = 0, len = timeElems.length; i < len; i++) {
  let date = Date.parse(timeElems[i].getAttribute("datetime"));
  timeElems[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML = ago(date);
}
```

Now you don't have to write out JS for each post manually. You could similarly use `getElementsByTagName('time')` assuming this is the only place you use that tag.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks a lot I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

this is very simple you can use some JS([/javascript-time-ago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/javascript-time-ago)) ready..

just use as example below..

> timeAgo.format(new Date()) ---> will output // "just now"

if you will give the date format to it, will give how much time ago.

Comment: Thanks, I will test it with Jekyll!

Answer (score 1):

First things first, your `ago` function can be simplified and reduced.

Then I'd use the *attribute starts with* selector with `querySelectorAll` to fetch the elements, and use `.forEach()` to set the `textContent` from the attribute.

```js
function render(n, unit) {
  return n + " " + unit + ((n == 1) ? "" : "s") + " ago";
}
const labels = ["year", "month", "day", "hour", "minute", "second"];
const products = [1, 60, 60, 24, 30, 365]
  .map((n, i, a) => a.slice(0, a.length-i).reduce((p, n) => p * n, 1));

function ago(date) {
  var seconds = Math.floor((new Date() - Date.parse(date)) / 1000);

  return labels.reduce((res, lab, i) => {
    const interval = Math.floor(seconds / products[i]);
    return res ? res : interval >= 1 ? render(interval, lab) : "";
  }, "");
}


document.querySelectorAll("[id^=postedon]").forEach(el =>
  el.querySelector('#' + el.id.replace('postedon', 'postedago'))
  .textContent = ago(el.getAttribute("datetime"))
);
```

```html
<time id="postedon0" datetime="2018-1-4 02:00:00 +0100">
  <span id="postedago0"></span>
</time>
<time id="postedon1" datetime="2018-1-7 02:00:00 +0100">
  <span id="postedago1"></span>
</time>
<time id="postedon2" datetime="2018-1-9 02:00:00 +0100">
  <span id="postedago2"></span>
</time>

<time id="postedon3" datetime="2018-1-13 02:00:00 +0100">
  <span id="postedago3"></span>
</time>
```

Also note that I'm using `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` since you're not actually setting any HTML content.

Note also that `Date.parse` doesn't work with that date format in Firefox.

Comment: Awesome, I like it! Thank you very much.

Comment: I get an error in the console: `TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function`.

Comment: @RobertFraktar: Yep, I had some mistakes. I think they're fixed, though I may be setting the wrong `.innerHTML` element. Checking...

Comment: @RobertFraktar: OK, I think I'm now setting the nested `span`. It can actually be simpler if it is always the first element inside the `postedon` element. If so, then it's just `el.firstElementChild.innerHTML = ago(...`

Comment: No errors now, but it outputs "undefined" on each post.

Comment: @RobertFraktar: Unfortunately I can't test it without any rendered data. The `new Date() - date` requires that I know what `date` actually is. Did you update all the code, so that `ago` uses `.find()`?

Comment: The date is being set in each post's front-matter, as described in OP.

Comment: @RobertFraktar: I had another mistake. But the `datetime` is actually in the format of `"2018-1-4 02:00:00 +0100"` ? If so, I don't know how `new Date() = date` could work.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see that I missed the `Date.parse` that you had. I'll update. Then it should work if you update to all the changes.

Comment: @RobertFraktar: Success! :D Sorry for all the changes. `Date.parse()` isn't working with that date format in Firefox, so I've had to bounce between it and Chrome. I've got it nailed down now (or so it seems).

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working now in both FF & Chrome! Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @RobertFraktar: You're welcome, and thanks for the feedback. I didn't want to leave it here in disrepair.

Answer (score 1):

Another example of how to calculate how long ago it was.

```
function ago(date) {
  var units = [
    { name : 'year', ms: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 365 },
    { name : 'month', ms: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 },
    { name : 'fortnight', ms : 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14 }, // yep.. I head that was a thing.
    { name : 'day', ms: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 },
    { name : 'hour', ms: 1000 * 60 * 60 },
    { name : 'second', ms: 1000 *60 },
  ];

  var ms = new Date() - date;
  var item = units.find( item => ms / item.ms > 1 );
  if (!item) item = units[ units.length - 1 ]; // if not found, use the last one.
  var value = Math.floor( ms / item.ms );

  return value + " " + item.name + ((value == 1) ? "" : "s") + " ago";
}
```